# Anyone have success setting up SharePoint 2010 with Sql Server 2008 on separate boxes?

Tags: sql, windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I am setting up SharePoint 2010 on one machine with SQL Server on a separate box to server as both the data store and serve reporting services (through SSRS/SP Integration).

In the past, I would install the WSS 3.0 for SharePoint 2007 on the SQL Server Box.  It appears that there is no existing option for SP 2010.  Am I missing something?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, I believe you can specify a Database server when you are configuring the product.

This is probably a good start: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667264.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - but it appears to lack any information on reporting services integration.

Comment: Update -- I traced through some of the links and found some "buried" articles on just what Im doing.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of "buried" articles ( for some reason I couldn't google them) in the Microsoft Sharpoint Documentation Tree:

(since I could not pust multiple links youre stick with this one)

[Configuring on Multiple servers - my specific case](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677365.aspx)

Comment: You can post multiple comments I suppose? Post them with the links, and I can add them.